# Appropriate way to creating postgresql database with subcategories?

Tags: database, postgresql, csv, database-design, workflow

I'm very new at working with databases.

I need to add a new table to existing database that I have.

The thing is that I need to add 200+ Materials such as Paint, Timber, Iron, etc.  to the database.

Every material has 4 values.  (weight, density, conductivity, cost)

Some of the material has sub categories. for example: timber has different sub_types(Oak, Pine, Ash, etc.)

And all those sub_types have different  (weight, density, conductivity, cost)

Some of the Materials have no Sub categories for example: (PVC Framed).

So my question is basically, Is it appropriate to put all those materials in  the same Table.
Or should I make a table for each Material because some of them have sub_categories and some don't?

So basically my worries are if some materials have sub_categories and others not is going to be bad for the database, because of the empty spaces.

Below is a screenshot of the table header from a `.csv` the sub_ categories are marked as material_type.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalizing your database will save you lots of headaches down the line.

I'm going with the assumption that "generic wood category" does not have (weight, density, conductivity, cost) attributes, as the type of wood is unknown. These parameters would apply to Oak, Pine etc.

I'd use a materials_category table:

```
category_id   PK
category_name
```

and a materials table:

```
category_id  Foreign Key
material_id  PK
material_name
material_weight ... etc
```

For the materials which don't belong to any category, you can create an "everything else" category so every material always belongs to a category, which should make the rest of the code a lot simpler.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be a good approach,  What columns should I make Primary Keys and Foreign Keys.  I would need to do that since the tables are "linked"?

Comment: Yes, a foreign key is necessary. I've put PK and FK notes on the columns.

Comment: Hi @peufeu, I have one additional question if you have the time: I'm building the DB, and some of the Materials have sub_categories in its sub_categories. How can I work with that ?

Comment: So, it's a tree? Look up "hierarchical data" and trees, like there: https://coderwall.com/p/whf3-a/hierarchical-data-in-postgres

Comment: Thank you @peufeu, Yes apparently it's a tree, or at least some of the materials are.  Example. Timber => Oak, Ash, Birch, etc, => Virgin, Recycled. I'll take a look at this.  I guess I have to build it  all in one table now using `Section 1.2.3.` no?

Comment: Think of it like a filesystem: categories are folders and subfolders, and materials would be files. If categories have no weight, cost etc attributes it would be better to have 2 tables since they are different things...